# Docker wordpress multisite with subdomains

Tags: wordpress, docker, subdomain, multisite

I'm looking for dockerized wordpress that supports multisite (with subdomains and NOT subdirectories). The best I found is installing it from scratch (at least it can be used as valuable approach):

[Dockerize wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954952/dockerize-wordpress)

or one with subdirectories:

https://hub.docker.com/r/dylanrhysscott/wordpress-multisite-docker/

Any advice how to get docker that runs wordpress with multisite support without subdirectories?